# Antlr 4 JDialog created by tree.inspect(parser) is automatically closed by JUnit

Tags: java, junit, executorservice, antlr4, invokeandwait

In Antlr 4, such code works in a general main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   .....
   SicstusPrologParser parser = new SicstusPrologParser(tokens);
   ParserRuleContext tree =(ParserRuleContext)parser.program();
   tree.inspect(parser);
}
```

The last statement pops up a model JDialog which shows the parser tree structure. But I copied the code into a junit test case as below:

```
 @Test
public void testParserClause() { //clause
    .....
   SicstusPrologParser parser = new SicstusPrologParser(tokens);
   ParserRuleContext tree =(ParserRuleContext)parser.program();
   tree.inspect(parser);
 }
```

The JDialog created by "tree.inpect(parser)"  has just been closed by junt before I clicked the "OK" button. I dived into the "inspect" function, its main logic flow is as the following:

```
   .....
 Callable<JDialog> callable = new Callable<JDialog>() {
    JDialog result;

    @Override
        public JDialog call() throws Exception {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                                         //fill the tree nodes and show the dialog.
                    result = showInDialog(viewer);
                }
            });

            return result;
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    try {
        return executor.submit(callable);
    }
    finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
```

Why is the model JDialog closed before I do sth with it? I used the return value of "inspect", but it still did work.

```
       Future<JDialog> fu = tree.inpect(parser);
       fu.get();
```

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A utility method is provided in case you need to wait for the window to close before proceeding:

```
Future<JDialog> future = tree.inspect(parser);
Utils.waitForClose(future.get());
```

Comment: `Utils.waitForClose` has been removed, see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/commit/4a1ec7df3828d2415680dfb6766c79caa3b449bb#diff-e414337876c195a0e9e6ab1e2fbcede6